# Managed property - Unable to set property

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I'm trying to use ManagedProperty:

From here

```
@ManagedBean(name = "SelectionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TableSelectionBean implements Serializable {
    private String selectionMode = "single";
    private Collection<Object> selection;
    private List<MonitoringData> monitoringData;
    private List<MonitoringData> selectionMonitoringData;
```

to here:

```
@ManagedBean(name="ActionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MonitoringActionBean implements Serializable {
    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    @ManagedProperty(value="{SelectionBean.selectionMonitoringData}")
    private List<MonitoringData> selectedMonitoring;
```

and i got the following error message:

com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to set property selectedMonitoring for managed bean ActionBean
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert {SelectionBean.selectionMonitoringData} of type class java.lang.String to interface java.util.List

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Does `TableSelectionBean` contain a getter for `selectionMonitoringData`?

Comment: Yes, contains getter and setter too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're forgetting the hashtag:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="{SelectionBean.selectionMonitoringData}")
```

Should be:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{SelectionBean.selectionMonitoringData}")
```